# Angular7 button onclock throws ERROR TypeError: _co.onClick is not a function at Object.eval [as handleEvent]

Tags: angular7

I have a component class like

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class LoginComponent {

  message = "";

  onClick() {
    this.message = 'Hey, How are You?';
    console.log(this.message);
    alert(this.message);
  }
}
```

and the button in html is like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="onClick()">Login to Dashboard</button>
```

But when clicks on the button, I'm getting below error

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.onClick is not a function at Object.eval [as handleEvent]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template can't see your onClick() function for some reason. When i got this error it was because i hadn't written my function yet. For you it may be because your html may be in the wrong template